# Difference between UIManagedDocument saveToURL and UIManagedDocumentContext save

Tags: core-data, ios5

I'm debugging a Core Data issue in my app (running on iOS 5), where the changes to existing managed objects are not being persisted between app sessions. If I use `[UIManagedDocumentContext save]`, nothing happens, and my changes are lost next time I restart the app. If I use `[UIManagedDocument saveToURL]`, however, the changes do get saved. The Apple docs are unclear as to which is the right way of persisting the updates. Can someone explain the difference between the two, and when to use each method?

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1842295&seqNum=10